# lxml file opening methods

Tags: python, lxml

I've generally been in the habit of writing:

```
with open('path/my_document.xml', 'rb') as xml_document:
    return etree.parse(xml_document)
```

I only recently realized I can just write

```
return etree.parse('path/my_document.xml')
```

Assuming I don't need to use the `xml_document` variable for anything else, are there real world scenarios in which there is a difference between the two?

Source code of `etree.parse`:

```
def parse(self, source, _BaseParser parser=None, *, base_url=None):
    u"""parse(self, source, parser=None, base_url=None)
    Updates self with the content of source and returns its root
    """
    cdef _Document doc = None
    try:
        doc = _parseDocument(source, parser, base_url)
        self._context_node = doc.getroot()
        if self._context_node is None:
            self._doc = doc
    except _TargetParserResult as result_container:
        # raises a TypeError if we don't get an _Element
        self._context_node = result_container.result
    return self._context_node
```

Comment: The first difference I see is, that in the first example you pass a file object to `etree.parse()`. In the second example you pass a string object and `etree.parse()` opens the file itself.